# Azure Tag for Azure Depolyment not working

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment

I am trying to create a Azure deployment with Tag parameter to put tag on the deployment using command  **New-AzResourceGroupDeployment** like -

```
 New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "demo" -TemplateFile "D:\Templates\storage.json" -Tag @{"CreatedFrom"="PS"; "Env"="Dev";}
```

but facing this issue -

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Tag'.
At line:1 char:102
+ ... Name "demo" -TemplateFile "D:\Templates\storage.json" -Tag @{"Crea ...
+                                                              ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.N
   ewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroupdeployment?view=azps-6.1.0#syntax) we can put tag parameter with `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` command but its not working for me.

Any help on what I am doing wrong here would be much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command works fine here. Make sure you have the latest version of the commands.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-6.1.0

Comment: The command runs successfully, where can I check the deployment tags?